# If have sticky post display post thumbnail

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm fairly new to php and WordPress. I'm trying to write an argument that states if I have a sticky post display the featured image in a banner I created and am not sure what to do this is what I've come up with thus far no idea if this is correct:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$query = new WP_Query( '$sticky' );

if ( have_posts('$sticky') ) :
    while ( have_posts('$sticky') ) : post_thumbnail();
        // loop code
    endwhile;
else :
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts were found.', 'textdomain' );
endif;
```

Right now I have it where the featured image is displayed for the newest regular post providing that it has a featured image if not space is left blank. I do not wish to have their featured images displayed in the banner I created.

Here is my current code for displaying the featured image of any blog post

```
<div class="hero-bg" style="background:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url()?>') no-repeat center center !important; background-size:cover !important; ">
  </div>
```

Comment: Your problem is unclear, at least to me. Please check this: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @flomei hopefully now it is more clear